# Load separate stylesheet for chrome with Modernizr?

Tags: javascript, css, html, modernizr

Is this even possible? I'm currently using browser detect but read about modernizrs feature detect. Problem is I'm not getting it. I just want to serve a separate stylesheet only for chrome. How is this possible?

This is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.chrome,
    yep: 'assets/css/chrome.css'
});
</script>
```

I downloaded the entire modernizr package. I didn't dare to download a customized build because im not sure what exactly I need.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr is intended as a way to check if a visitor's browser supports certain features, and if it doesn't it gives you easy methods to load alternatives. It's not the right tool for browser detection.